# ActivityInfo[] is null for PackageManager.getInstalledPackages()

Tags: android, android-activity, null, package-managers, package-info

Trying to retrieve all activities for each package results in null ActivityInfo array for all of them:

```
List<PackageInfo> packageInfos = mPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(
                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES &
                PackageManager.GET_SERVICES &
                PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS &
                PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS &
                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

for (PackageInfo p : packageInfos) 
    Log.wtf(TAG, p.packageName + ": " + (p.activities == null ? "null" :"not null"));
```

***p.activities*** for all packages is null. According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#activities it shouldn´t be null because GET_ACTIVITIES flag is set.

Where is the problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I messed with the bitwise operators. Must have used OR operator (`|`) instead the AND one (`&`), like this:

```
List<PackageInfo> packageInfos = mPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(
                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES |
                PackageManager.GET_SERVICES |
                PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS |
                PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS |
                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

However, this call results in a `TransactionTooLargeException` because of size limit of data changed between different processes in Android, so most probaly returned `packageInfos` list will be null or empty